# POSTMAN,REST,JSON

Tags: json, spring

```
Json Data

[
{
"city":["Abbeville","Addamsville"],
"state":"Alabama",
"country":"US"
},
{
"city":["Batsville","ciarsville"],
"state":"Alaska",
"country":"US"
}
]
```

This is my Json Data and when iam posting this data in Postman to hit to my java service and created a POJO to the JSON as below,but it was throwing exception as

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  
Failed to read HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could 
not read document: Can not deserialize instance of 
com.js.agtools.domain.Cities out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@23fd2bf6; line: 1, column: 1]; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can 
not deserialize instance of com.js.agtools.domain.Cities out of START_ARRAY 
token.
```

Cities.java

```
package com.js.agtools.domain;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class Cities {
@JsonProperty("city")
private List<String> city;
@JsonProperty("state")
private String state;
@JsonProperty("country")
private String country;
@JsonProperty("city")
public List<String> getCity() {
return city;
}
@JsonProperty("city")
public void setCity(List<String> city) {
this.city = city;
}
@JsonProperty("state")
public String getState() {
return state;
}
@JsonProperty("state")
public void setState(String state) {
this.state = state;
}
@JsonProperty("country")
public String getCountry() {
return country;
}
@JsonProperty("country")
public void setCountry(String country) {
this.country = country;
}
}
```

StateController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/states",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> fetchStates(@RequestBody Cities cities){
for(int i=0;i<cities.getCity().size();i++){
System.out.println(cities.getCity().get(i));
}
return new ResponseEntity<>(cities, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Please some one suggest me why iam getting this error.I am not getting a solution to this from many hours.I think iam somewhere missing something in pojo.Please some one tell me where iam doing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is expecting only one `Cities` object, but you are passing an array of it. Change
`@RequestBody Cities cities`

to

`@RequestBody List<Cities> cities`

if you really want an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is an array. and you are parsing it as a object.

You can parse it as

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class))
```

where mapper is object of ObjectMapper class.

Comment: where should i add this in my controller right,but even when iam posting this data from postman to /states url,it was showing the above erroe.So where should i add the above line exactly